# Advantages of RNN over DNN in prediction

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I am going to work on a problem that needs to be addressed with either RNN or Deep Neural Nets. In general, the problem is predicting financial values. So, because I am given the sequence of financial data as an input, I thought that RNN would be better. On the other hand, I think that if I can fit the data into some structure, I can train with DNN much better because the training phase is easier in DNN than RNN. For example, I could get last 1-month info and keep 30 inputs and predict 31'th day while using DNN. 
I don't understand the advantage of RNN over DNN in this perspective. My first question is about the proper usage of RNN or DNN in this problem.

My second questions are somehow basic. While training RNN, isn't it possible for a network to get "confused"? I mean, consider the following input: 10101111, and our inputs are one digits 0 or 1 and we have 2-sequences (1-0,1-0,1-1,1-1) Hereafter 1, comes 0 several times. And then at the end, after 1 comes 1. While training, wouldn't this become a major problem? That is, why the system not gets confused while training this sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question is phrased a bit problematically.
 First, DNNs are a *class* of architectures. A Convolutional Neural Network differs greatly from a Deep Belief Network or a simple Deep MLP. There are feed forward architectures (e.g. TDNN) fit for timeseries prediction but it depends on you, whether you're more interested in research or just solving your problem.

Second, RNNs are as "deep" as it gets. Considering the most basic RNN, the Elman Network: During training with Backpropagation through time (BPTT) they are unfolded in time - backpropagating over T timesteps. Since this backpropagation is done not only *vertically* like in a standard DNN but also *horizontally* over T-1 context layers, the past activations of the hidden layers from T-1 timesteps *before* the present are actually considered for the activation at the current timestep. This illustration of an unfolded net might help in understanding what I just wrote ([source](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/recurrentjs/)):

[image]

This makes RNNs so powerful for timeseries prediction (and should answer both your questions). If you have more questions, read about Elman Networks. LSTMs etc. will only confuse you. Understanding Elman Networks and BPTT is the needed foundation to understand *any* other RNN.

And one last thing you'll need to look out for: The [vanishing gradient problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_gradient_problem). While it's tempting to say let's make T=infinity and give our RNN as much memory as possible: It doesn't work. There are many ways working around this problem, LSTMs are quite popular at the moment and there are even some proper LSTM implementations around nowadays. But it's important to know that a basic Elman Network *could* really struggle with T=30.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a question related with the image. In that image we have hello and hello.length=5+1 hidden units. If i have longer series, then do i have to carry longer hidden states. Or the number of hidden states is my network's memory? For exampe if it is 3, then network can remember at most 3 sequences, like n-grams,n=3.

Comment: In the example a hidden layer has exactly 1 hidden neuron, not 5+1. Careful, the image shows the *unfolded net*, not the RNN itself! Your memory is not related to the layer. It's the time horizon (=T) which is not a parameter visible in the actual architecture since it's only defined and used in the learning algorithm (BPTT). Here is an example  showing a network with more than 3 hidden units : http://mnemstudio.org/neural-networks-elman.htm The hidden unit (activations) have the same meaning as in feedforward nets: They're a (local but not temporal) abstraction of your input.

Comment: Thank you for your correction. Then if I have infinite sequence, I dont have to keep all hidden unit, just the one in t-1 'th step. Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: You need to keep *every* hidden *layer* from steps t (present), t-1, t-2, t-3, ..., t-T. Again, these are called context layers and it'll come clear reading about BPTT.

Answer (score 2):

As you answered yourself - RNN are for **sequences**. If data has sequential nature (time series) than it is preferable to use such model over DNN and other "static" models. The main reason is that RNN can model **process** which is responsible for each conequence, so for example given sequences

```
0011100
0111000
0001110
```

RNN will be able to build a model, that "after seeing '1' I will see two more" and correctly build a prediction when seeing

```
0000001**** -> 0000001110
```

While in the same time, for DNN (and other non sequential models) there is no relation between these three sequences, in fact the only common thing for them is that "there is 1 on forth position, so I guess it is always like that".

Regarding the second question. Why it won't get confused? Because it models **sequences**, because it has **memory**. It makes its recisions based on everything that was observed before, and assuming that your signal has any type of regularity, there is always some vent in the past that differentiate between two possible paths of signals. Once again, such phenomena are much better addressed by RNN than non-recurrent models. See for example natural language and enormous progress given by LSTM-based models in recent years.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. What I dont understand is this: Consider sequence 000111 for training the RNN. After we train RNN, I given 000? as an input to predict fourth element. While training, after 0 most of the time comes 1. Then how it remembers that after 000 there must come 1? Therefore I thought that if I can find an input representation that can fit all inputs in a resonable structure, it would perform better

Comment: RNN is not a naive bayes; it does not simply count "how many times something occures". It has **memory**; it learns relations between consequtive signals. It learns, that for example "after exactly three zeros there is high probability of 1", it build a conditional probability distribution which is updated with each step in "time".

Comment: Does RNN can memorize more than unfold size? let's say unfold size T = 3, than can it be better compare to DNN with 3 input nodes(like unfolding)? the reason that I ask this question is.. it seems to me that BPTT occurs only with T=3 and this is longest memory the network can remember.

Comment: yes, it can learn to memorise longer sequences than unroll length T, as despite BPTT you still have the hidden state that is propagated further. It is not much, but it is qualitatively different from regular net with T inputs.